# How to make unordered list with image on left and 2 list items beside it on right

Tags: html, css

So I have an unordered list like this

```
<ul>
    <li>image.jpg</li>
    <ul>
        <li>name</li>
        <li>description</li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

I want to have the image on the left side and the name and description(one below the other on the right side of the image.  Is it possible to do this.  I have tried setting the li > ul > li's to display block and the ul before that to a display of inline.  Also have tried floats.  Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/tU3V4/

Comment: Somewhat but I was trying to do it with list items if possible.  I need to have both list items to the right of the image directly.  The description should only be a couple of words.

Comment: What is wrong with using a div inside of your list? You could do something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/tU3V4/3/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want, but try this in your css:

```
li, ul, ul ul {
    float: left;
}
ul ul li {
    float: none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Cf3EY/